# error in findViewById

Tags: android

Hi I'm doing an android gps tutorial and I'm getting an error I don't understand (I'm pretty new to android dev). Im getting the error at

```
position = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
```

where `activity_main` seems to be the problem. Could somebody explain what the problem is? thanks.

```
import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GPSActivity extends Activity
{
    WebView position;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item);

        position = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        position.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
    {
        String Text ="My current location is: " + "Latitud="
                + loc.getLatitude() + "Longitud =" + loc.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        String url ="http://maps.google.com/staticmap?center="
                + loc.getLatitude() +loc.getLatitude()
                + "&zoom=14&size=512x512&maptype=mobile/&markers="
                + loc.getLatitude() + loc.getLongitude();
        position.loadUrl(url);

    }
}
```

the error is activity main cannot be resolved or is not a field, I think the id is in activity_main but correct me if I'm wrong, here it is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <Webview
     android:id="@+id/webview"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you tell us what the error is?

Comment: Could you post the XML file that contains that id?

Comment: Is `activity_list_main` declared in `activity_list_item` xml file?

Comment: To help you out, we need the error output and the XML file

Comment: the answers are up top

Comment: Make sure you have a webview with an id `activity_main` inside activity_list_item.xml

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding lately? Also activity_main is usually a naming convention reserved for the layout of the main activity, but it appears you are trying to assign it to a webview. As stated before, if you post the relevant xml we would be more able to help you.

Comment: Problem is you are giving the wrong Id to get the web View

Comment: Oh additionally, you will want to remove the import android.R statement, since it will look for the ids in android.R, but they will be in your_package_name.R

Comment: `position = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);` after you remove the import android.R.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change it to

```
position = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

Also make sure you'e setting the correct layout

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

The reason is that the id of the `WebView` is not `R.id.activity_main`. In your case it is `R.id.webview`. The ID values are set in your XML layout via `android:id="@+id/webview`

Another possible issue. Remove `import android.R;` as well.

Comment: Thanks but, I'm getting "webview cannot be resolved or is not a field" now

Comment: Make sure you're using the correct layout. Is the XML you posted `activity_main.xml`? Try `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` at the same time

Comment: When I change that I get the same error for activity_main, yea thats activity_main.xml

Comment: You are still getting this after removing the `import android.R;` statement?

Comment: Your explanation is what really helped me.  When are people going to stop naming things the same thing in different places?  It is incredibly un-helpful.  For example, if they had called the ID "activity_main_id" or "activityMainXMLID" or literally anything else besides it's name elsewhere, which is activity_main

Answer (score 2):

This is the reason it can't find your resources:

```
import android.R;
```

It expecting to find your R related stuff in the android.R that is precompiled. You need to remove that line and import your package's R not the precompiled R.

### Solution

Remove the `import android.R` line.

Also ensure your project compiles and can generate the R.java during the build process.

Answer (score 1):

`position = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);` after you remove the import android.R.

It is looking for webview in android.R.id, but it is located in your_package_name.R.id.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 
import android.R;

You will probabl still get errors that it is not recognized. This is because you are in a default package instead of your project package. You can get around it by importing your .R
So if you package name is com.GPS
then import com.GPS.R

Answer (score 0):

```
    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
    WebView   mWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView2);
```

I did that :)
I was able

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue with `findViewByID(R.id.activity_main);`, and I spent days trying out all the solutions I saw online.

**I solved the problem using the following method:**

I went to the XML document and gave my layout a name (ID): `activity_main`.

This line of code popped up in the TextView of my XML document: `android:id="@+id/activity_main"`.

Immediately, I stopped having the `activity_main` problem.

**Note:** I also do not have the `import.android.R statement`.